# How does resistance, voltage and current work in a circuit with a small load

Tags: voltage, led, current

If I intend to run an LED with a 5V source voltage and an LED forward voltage of 2V at 20ma it is my understanding that a 150 ohm resistor is suited.

I get this from using the formula `V = IR` rearranged to `R = V/I`.
`R = 3/0.02`
A 3V voltage difference at 20ma.

This works in practice as well, the LED is well lit and I get the forward voltage and current I expect when measured.

How exactly are these concepts related? It is my understanding that at at V voltage with R resistance, a maximum of I current will be allowed through. Is my understanding of these concepts over simplified or valid?

Comment: "At V voltage" is inaccurate.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Is my concept of voltage misguided?

Comment: Note that if the LED has a maximum rating of 20 mA and you run it at 20 mA continuously, it will not have a long life. Either PWM it or run it at 50% to 75% of its max rating for a long life.

Comment: From what you have written here your understanding appears reasonable and valid.  I could be missing something but I don't see any logic flaws.

Comment: The "a maximum of" part is mistaken. Current, voltage, and resistance are precisely related - or one of the measurements is wrong or inapplicable.  For example, while it works for the resistor, you can't really express the behavior of an LED as a simple resistance.  Given that the forward voltage on an LED is not ultimately fixed,  there are still a number of unknowns.

Comment: Don’t we still have a maximum forward voltage we can go by. For example an LED with a maximum forward voltage of 3V, couldn’t we select a resistor to safely supply 2V at a safe current.

Comment: You can certainly select a current limit resistor in consideration of the forward voltage as a function of current, but no, there is no maximum forward voltage.  It will keep rising with increasing current (albeit to a very small degree) until the junction is destroyed resulting in an open circuit (or briefly a short until it vaporizes) at which point the forward voltage rises dramatically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very important to remember that Ohm's Law applies to the voltage **across a resistor** and the current **through the resistor**.

If you know the source voltage and the LED forward voltage then you can use Kirchhoff's Voltage Law to determine what the voltage **must be** across the resistor. Then you apply Ohm's Law to determine what value of resistance will result in the desired current, now that you know what the resistor voltage must be.